# Sum of two random variables as a sum of functions, fallacy in logic

Tags: probability-theory

This might be a silly newbie question, but could you please help me find the fallacy in my logic?

Consider binomial distributions X ~ Bin(10, p) and Y ~ Bin(15, p). Since random variables are functions taking a random outcome as input, X + Y is also a function. If we view it as a sum of functions, (X + Y)(**a**) = X(**a**) + Y(**a**) where **a** is a random outcome in the sample space. As I understand, in binomial distribution the outcome **a** could be some number of successes (e.g. 5). But since we are evaluating X and Y at the same point **a** how could we view this sum as the total number of successes in the combined experiment? Or should I view **a** different for both X and Y? How should I think about it as a sum of two functions?

Comment: The sum $X + Y$ isn't defined without additional information. You've only specified their distributions individually but to make sense of $X + Y$ you need to know their joint distribution. The simplest option is that they're independent but there are others.

Comment: Related to responses already given: Your outcome space needs to be specific, say, each outcome $a$ representing the heads/tails result of 25 separate trials. So $a=(a_1,..., a_{25})$ with $a_i\in\{heads, tails\}$ for each $i$.  Then we can define $X(a)=\sum_{i=1}^{10}a_i$, $\tilde{X}(a)=\sum_{i=2}^{11}a_i$ and both $X$ and $\tilde{X}$ are $Bin(10,p)$. We can define $Y(a)=\sum_{i=11}^{25}a_i$, $\tilde{Y}(a)=\sum_{i=1}^{15}a_i$ and both $Y$ and $\tilde{Y}$ are $Bin(15,p)$. And $X+Y$, $X+\tilde{Y}$, $\tilde{X}+Y$, $\tilde{X}+\tilde{Y}$ all make sense but have different distributions.

Comment: Thank you all, now it makes perfect sense to me!

Answer (score 3):

You can't make sense out of it without more context. If $X,Y$ are functions, you have to ask what domain are they functions on? If $X$ and $Y$ have different domains, $X+Y$ doesn't make sense.

There are multiple ways to realize $X$ and $Y$ on the same probability space, which lead to different distributions of $X+Y$. You would never try to make sense of $X+Y$ as a function without additional information.

Example $1$: There is coin with probability of heads equal to $p$. Flip the coin $25$ times. Let $X$ be the number of heads in the first ten flips and let $Y$ be the number of heads in the last fifteen flips. Then $X+Y\sim \text{Bin}(25,p)$ is the number of heads in all $25$ flips.

Example $2$: There is a coin with probability of heads equal to $p$. Flip the coin $15$ times and let $X$ be the number of heads in the first ten flips. Let $Y$ be the number of heads in all fifteen flips. Then $X+Y$ counts any heads in the first ten flips twice, and any heads in the  last five once.

The distributions are not the same in these two examples.